# iOS7 auto layout with Tabbar combined with UIScrollView and zoomable UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a somewhat complicated setup where I have a zoomable `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView`. The zooming and everything related to it works correctly.
However because of the autoLayout implemented in iOS6/7 I cannot seem to find a way to have the constraints account for the `UITabBar`. Therefore now the image is cut off at the bottom as you can see in this picture: 
[image: image of tabbar problem]

Where I want it to display like this:
[image: image of the tabbar correctly]

So far I have been messing around a lot with all the constraints and even considered dumping AutoLayout at all, only to find other problems with the layout later on.

So I want to use the AutoLayout features, but not sure how to get them right.
To make sure the zooming part works correctly I have the constraints setup like this at the moment:
[image: image of the scrollView constraints]
[image: image of the imageView constraints]

(ScrollView left, ImageView right)

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction on how to add/modify a constraint so that the `TabBar` is respected and the `UIImageView` is displayed correctly.

Comment: Ve you tried without autolayout?

Comment: See my question where I state the following: "So far I have been messing around a lot with all the constraints and even considered dumping AutoLayout at all, only to find other problems with the layout later on." So yes, I have tried.. :)

Comment: try once to uncheck extend edges for both topbars and bottom bars which is available for viewcontroller

Comment: I have tried to uncheck these checkboxes, and in the end this fixed my issue. I also removed all constraints, and set them automatically, this combined with the unchecking of those Extended Edges checkboxes fixed it. Thanks!!

Comment: welocme happy to help you

Comment: if you found it is useful accept the below answer it may help others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i said earlier Try to uncheck the view controller's extend Edges which will available in the viewController's property

uncheck both under Top bars and under bottom bars and try once. Happy for this helps you

[image]